# Excel Macro not working properly when called from custom button

Tags: excel, vba, custom-controls

I created a macro in Excel 2010, that works quite fine when called from the Macros dialog or the VB window. All's fine at that point. Now, I tried my hand at customized ribbons, and used Custom UI Editor to create a new tab, with custom icons to call my macro. And it's not fine.

The call to the macro works, the macro seems to run properly, scanning each sheet as it should, looking for comments and acting on them, but when it's completed, almost none of the comments were modified as they should have been.

And that's my issue: when I run the macro "normally", it works as planned, it's only when I try to call it from its custom icon that it doesn't do what it's supposed to do (while still seeming to when clicked).

Anyone has an idea what could be wrong?

I don't think it's the code, as I said, it works fine when called from Macros or the VB window

---

Edit: As I said, I don't think the code is the problem, as it executes without error (it just doesn't do what it's supposed to), but as requested, I post it here:

```
Sub ImportCommentsFromWord(control As IRibbonControl)

Dim xComment As Comment
Dim xSheet As Worksheet
Dim wApp As Object

'Opens Word if not already open
On Error Resume Next
Set wApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

wApp.Visible = False

For Each xSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

'Activates each sheet one after another
xSheet.Activate
sName = xSheet.Name
expName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + sName + ".docx"

'Checks if there are comments in active sheet
For Each xComment In xSheet.Comments
    CommsInSheet = 1
Next

If CommsInSheet = 1 Then

    'Opens the translated document to import comments into the sheet
    wApp.Documents.Open (expName)
    wApp.Selection.ClearFormatting
    wApp.Selection.Find.MatchWildcards = False
    wApp.Selection.WholeStory
    wApp.Selection.MoveLeft
    FileEnd = 0
    'Imports comments until end of file is reached
    While FileEnd = 0
        wApp.Selection.ExtendMode = True
        wApp.Selection.MoveRight
        With wApp.Selection.Find
            .Text = "^l"
        End With
        wApp.Selection.Find.Execute
        DestCell = Mid(wApp.Selection.Text, 2, Len(wApp.Selection.Text) - 2)
        wApp.Selection.ExtendMode = False
        wApp.Selection.MoveRight
        wApp.Selection.ExtendMode = True
        With wApp.Selection.Find
            .Text = "^l"
        End With
        wApp.Selection.Find.Execute
        wApp.Selection.ExtendMode = False
        DestComm = Left(wApp.Selection.Text, Len(wApp.Selection.Text) - 1)
        wApp.Selection.MoveRight
        wApp.Selection.MoveLeft
        wApp.Documents.Add DocumentType:=0
        wApp.Selection.Text = DestComm
        With wApp.Selection.Find
            .Text = "^p"
            .Replacement.Text = Chr(10)
        End With
        wApp.Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        wApp.Selection.WholeStory
        DestComm = Left(wApp.Selection.Text, Len(wApp.Selection.Text) - 1)
        wApp.ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=False
        If Right(DestComm, 11) = "END_OF_FILE" Then
            DestComm = Left(DestComm, Len(DestComm) - 11)
            FileEnd = 1
        End If
        xSheet.Range(DestCell).Comment.Text Text:=DestComm
    Wend

    'Closes the Word document
    wApp.ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=False

End If

CommsInSheet = 0

Next

wApp.Visible = True
Set wApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It's hard to provide assistance with a blindfold on. Post some relevant sections of the code noting the code line that the code fails on.

Comment: Posted, but I still think the issue is with some setting I forgot somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the solution myself: the issue was in the xml code of the customized ribbon, it was calling the wrong macro, so of course it didn't work as expected...