# Excel VBA Macro called from VB IDE works fine, but fails when called from a button until file is saved multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen a few posts addressing things similar to what I'm experiencing, but nothing definitively resolves my issue.  If I need to post this in a different Stack forum, please let me know.

I have multiple Buttons on an Excel sheet (NOT `ActiveX CommandButtons`) which are displaying some strange behaviors.

They are all assigned various Macros, but they all fail within certain conditions, except one (see "TLDR" below).  I get the standard `"Cannot run the macro ''Workbook Name Here.xlsm'!'Subroutine_Called''.  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."` error.  I get this error on ALL of the macros assigned to the 15++ buttons.

Each Macro indeed exists.  When executing the Macros from the `VB IDE` they work *just fine*.  When executing the Macros from the `Macros` button (`"View ToolBar" --> "Macros"`) and selecting the Macros and clicking the `Run` button, they work *just fine*.  When looping through the buttons through `VBA` to pull the `Button.OnAction` string and pulling out the workbook name, and then calling ***THAT*** from within the Loop works *just fine*.  The Code is not the problem.  It's a problem with Excel itself.

Here's the kicker ***(TLDR)***:
I've already selected the "Enable Macros" button when the security warning first pops up when the workbook opens ([image: as seen here]), but the Macros fail to run from the buttons.  If I save it a few times and open it again, there will be a Macro security warning at the top, just under the formula bar ([image: as seen here]).  The Macros still do not work from the Buttons even then (Again - they all work fine from `VB IDE` or the `Run Macro` dialog from the `View` toolbar).  The **only** time the Macros work from the Buttons is when the document is a Trusted Document.  How do I change this behavior, and can it be done programmatically?

My Concern is it exposes the names of the Macros and any/all parameters being sent in plain text which I am hoping to avoid.  Has anyone else experienced this specific phenomena?  I thought I had an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093647/excel-macro-not-working-properly-when-called-from-custom-button) until the author mentioned he's doing a specific Ribbon Button setup and called the wrong macro - this is not my problem. . .

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the buttons are linked to the open workbook and not to some other workbook?

Comment: Was the file you are using downloaded from the internet? If so, you may need to "unblock" it to make macros in it work.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I have authored this file myself from the ground up and have confirmed 100% the macros are indeed linked to the open workbook (only workbook opened besides my personal book when I used `assign macro`.  I have also provided a few more details in the comment below to braX.

Comment: @braX, I could not tag you as well on my comment to Tim, - the file has been created from scratch on my own.  The phenomenon does not occur when the file is a "Trusted File" - I have been able to confirm this much.  When I save this file as a new file, it is no longer a trusted file but a new instance and even after "enabling macros" on the new file (just a copy mind you), I get the warning, and it isn't until the new file is a "Trusted File" that the warning goes away.  This is very bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, I think I finally found the cause of this dilemma.  It dawned on me that the stupid thing was crashing more and more and more, so, I did what any reasonable person would - copied all the sheets over to a brand new `xlsm` book.  Then, I copied the text of the VBA Modules into a separate Text editor, and recreated them all.  All the forms I had were safe (THANKFULLY) so exporting those and importing them to the new one was simple enough to do.

***A major pitfall to be aware of:*** there was a warning about links to other files - turns out it had kept links to the old document in the BUTTONS (of all things)!!  I used `Edit Links` under the `Data` Ribbon [image: menu] (grayed out now because they're all gone!  WOOT!

Everything seems to be working fine now!

I have to give [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954669/excel-crashes-when-opening-trusted-document-with-macros-or-enabling-macros) (and subsequently allula at Ozgrid as well even though the [linked article](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/179860/) there is broken) some major Kudos.  This is what led me to this solution to begin with.  I'll be cross commenting on the linked post about my experience too in case nobody finds this one.

Additionally, as an added protection measure, I made the path of the workbook a trusted path and provided a subroutine to give the intended users this option without having to do it manually, only doing so when they accept it and removing it if they move the file and select "no" on the same request prompt.